# Can't change keyboard language layout?

Tags: windows-xp, installation, keyboard-layout

When I installed Windows XP, I didn't install support for my native language: Croatian.

I used a friends CD created with nLite and the languages where removed. How can I install the correct keyboard layout without re-installing?

**There is no Croatian to choose from when I go to selection language**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If nLite was used to strip the languages out, there is no way to install them afterwards. nLite warns about this during the creation of the new CD, as this is tightly controlled within Windows. As per the [nLite](http://www.msfn.org/board/component-not-remove-so-mui-language-pack-can-installed-t106262-pid-703708.html&mode=threaded#entry703708) forum here, to install a MUI you also need the Help & Support component.

```
MUI require "Help & Support" component
```

You could use your install CD and try and do a repair on Windows XP, however I am not sure if this will work.

Answer (score 2):

Copy the file **kbdcr.dll** from another (Croatian) Windows XP computer to your folder **c:\windows\system32** (or expand from an original Windows XP CDROM)

Open regedit and navigate to **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\ System\ CurrentControlSet\ Control\ keyboard layouts** and search for kbdcr.dll (0000041A on my machine, when I Google it says 00020405 for Croatian keyboard layout, but I found Czech/programmer in this folder)

now edit the Registry Key **HKEY_CURRENT_USER\ keyboard layout\ preload**, change the "1" value setting to the matching key from HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\ System\ CurrentControlSet\ Control\ keyboard layouts (e.g. 0000041A)

Done and Dusted!

(Note: Preload\2 is used if you want to be able to switch between two keyboard layouts.)

Comment: +1 Manual labor. Painful. But it does work thought.

Comment: i was quite active in a netbookforum back then when they first came with tiny SSDs and nLite was touted to be the best thing since sliced bread. of course many users went overzelous and ripped a needed keyboard layout ... so i'm quite used to this particular question. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can install support for Croatian after installing Windows XP. See **Control Panel**->**Regional and Language Settings**.

Comment: i tried that; but there's isn't Croatian (and many other languages) showed there;

Answer (score 0):

Have your language bar turned on, right click it, settings, add your keyboard and do not forget to have Windows never change it for you based on what you type.

Answer (score 0):

> i tried that; but there's isn't
>   Croatian (and many other languages)
>   showed there;

You'll have to use a different installation disk (one which has all regional packs installed, and it doesn't matter which XP edition it is) to install Croatian, after you installed 'nLite' Windows on your machine. 
*CP - Regional... - Install/uninstall additional languages*
You don't need to reinstall or repair, the problem will only repeat itself if you do it with a 'nLite' installation disk.

Answer (score 0):

> http://hr.download.hr/program-cro-keyboard.html

I hope this helps!

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score -2):

https://www.4shared.com/rar/33bShcFJce/crokeyb.html

Extract .rar file, copy .dll file on c:/windows/system32,
apply reg files 1., 2., go to language options and set language(in my case Croatian), reboot pc.

Hope this will help someone!
Pozdrav

Comment: This might be totally legit, but some reasons for concern: **1)** `rar` file from **2)** file sharing service which you have to **3)** extract a `dll` to the system directory. Might be fine, and I don't want to discourage answers from a **4)** new user but use common sense!

Comment: Yes, voting to delete.